# Tabulator - pagination row counts & grouped data

Tags: javascript, vue.js, pagination, tabulator

I'm using a custom footer to display pagination information like:
Rows 50 to 60 out of 100

It works very well including when using filters.

But it breaks with grouped data.
Let's say I've got 60 rows in 30 groups of 2 rows, the table will display 90 rows
But since the group headers are not counted as rows by Tabulator API, my pagination information quickly become wrong with things like
Rows 64 to 72 out of 60

I'm using the dataLoaded, dataFiltered & pageLoaded callbacks and the getPageSize
Is there anything to prevent the pagination module from counting group headers as rows?

Comment: Looks like you might have found a bug there, it might be worth creating a [Bug Report](https://github.com/olifolkerd/tabulator/issues/new?assignees=&labels=Possible+Bug&template=bug_report.md&title=) so that it can be fixed

Comment: OK it's done! :-)